# Infinite loop in c due to rounding?

Tags: c, while-loop, floating-point, infinite-loop, cs50

The following code is looping infinitely.  I believe it may be a rounding issue though not entirely sure.

I am fairly new to C so not sure why I'm getting the infinite looping that I'm getting. The code seems to make sense though keeps looping.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>



int main(void){

float quarter = .25;
int Qtr = 0;
float dime = .10;
int Dm = 0;
float nickel = .5;
int Nck = 0;
float penney = .01;
int Pn = 0;
float change;  
float userInput;
float newspaperCost;

do{
  printf("How much is the news paper today: \n");
  newspaperCost = GetFloat();
  printf("Amount Tendered: ");
  userInput = GetFloat();
  printf("You entered $%2.2f\n", userInput); 
  change = userInput - newspaperCost;
  printf("Change: $%2.2f\n", change); 
}

while(newspaperCost <= 0);

   while(change > 0){

  printf("%f\n", change);

  while(change - quarter > 0){

  change = change - quarter;
  Qtr++;

  }

  while(change - dime > 0){

  change = change - dime;
  Dm++;

  }

  while(change - nickel > 0){

  change = change - nickel;
  Nck++;

  }

  while(change - penney > 0){

  change = change - penney;
  Pn++;


  }

   } 

 printf("Your change consists of %d quarters, %d dimes, %d nickels, and %d pennies\n", Qtr, Dm, Nck, Pn);
   } //end main
```

Comment: If you want it to break out of the first loop the `do { } while`, then compare if the user input was 0 instead of less than 0. News paper cost can never be below zero. `while(newspaperCost != 0); ` Can you explain where the infinite loop is at? is it after the user has exited?

Comment: What is `GetFloat()`?

Comment: cs50.h is a library specific to an online tutorial I am using and GetFloat is a  function inside this library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a logic error in the last `while` loop.

Instead of

```
while(change - penney > 0){
   change = change - penney;
   Pn++;
}
```

Use

```
while(change > 0){
   change = change - penney;
   Pn++;
}
```

Comment: @ndjustin20, glad I was able to help.

Comment: @ndjustin20 To elaborate a bit, the problem is the surrounding `while (change > 0)` loop which is a bit hard to see due to poor code formatting. This surrounding loop can now be removed or changed to an `if` since the modified condition of the last inner `while` loop is the same.

Comment: Arkku thank you for pointing that out I appreciate the feedback.  I have it formatted better in gedit but was having issues getting the code to look right ie indented on SOF.  I'm seemingly off still by a penny when getting an odd number for change.  I updated the code to print out after each iteration of the while loops quarters through penny's and the last while loop is producing a -.010000 each time.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use floating point to represent currency.
- Prefer double over float unless you have a good reason.
- penny*
- You're not using any equality operators with floating point operands, so you probably have a logical error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
do{
  printf("How much is the news paper today: \n");
  newspaperCost = GetFloat();
  printf("Amount Tendered: ");
  userInput = GetFloat();
  printf("You entered $%2.2f\n", userInput); 
  change = userInput - newspaperCost;
  printf("Change: $%2.2f\n", change); 
} while(newspaperCost <= 0);
```

Won't exit this loop while `newspaperCost <= 0`. I'm assuming you aren't inputting a negative number at

```
  printf("How much is the news paper today: \n");
  newspaperCost = GetFloat();
```

That's why you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Umm, you got the “won't exit this loop” backwards – the loop repeats only _while_ `newspaperCost <= 0`, not until.

Comment: This was my intention for this particular loop.